# ddins verb in J ODBC library mangling SQL table name?

Tags: j

I am having trouble doing a bulk insert using ddins from the J ODBC library. The error message is "Invalid object name" and the object name included in the error message is indeed invalid, but also not what I typed. All the underscores and periods have been removed.  Note that other SQL operations, including INSERT, work fine with this same table. Does anyone know what is going on? The database I am connected to is SQL Server. My J version is 802. My operating system is Windows 7 Professional (64 bit)

Any help appreciated.    -Michael

Some sample output for context:

```
dddbms ch
┌────┬────────┬─────────┬──────────┬─────┬──────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬─┬─┬───┐
│ODBC│t4bwhsql│US\mberry│T4BSQL01AD│MSSQL│12.00.5000│sqlncli11.dll│11.00.2100│3│1│256│
└────┴────────┴─────────┴──────────┴─────┴──────────┴─────────────┴──────────┴─┴─┴───┘

query
select sales_region, country, historic_save_rate, target_save_rate from t4b.sales.r_bl_inside_sales_ccf_country_target


sh=: query ddsel ch
sh
6260928

ddfet sh

┌────────┬─────────┬───┬────┐
│Americas│Argentina│0.8│0.83│
└────────┴─────────┴───┴────┘

ddend sh
0

'truncate table t4b.sales.r_bl_inside_sales_ccf_country_target' ddsql ch
0

'insert into t4b.sales.r_bl_inside_sales_ccf_country_target(sales_region, country, historic_save_rate, target_save_rate) values(''Americas'', ''Argentina'', 0.8, 0.83)' ddsql ch
0

sh=: query ddsel ch

sh

71014208

ddfet sh

┌────────┬─────────┬───┬────┐
│Americas│Argentina│0.8│0.83│
└────────┴─────────┴───┴────┘

ddend sh
0

data
┌────────┬─────────────┬────────┬────┐
│Americas│Argentina │0.820513│0.83│
│Americas│Bolivia │0.923077│ 0.9│
│Americas│Brazil │0.909091│ 0.9│
│Americas│Canada │0.795918│0.81│
│Americas│Chile │ 0.85│0.86│
│Americas│Colombia │0.904762│ 0.9│
│Americas│Costa Rica │0.805556│0.82│
│Americas│Ecuador │0.888889│ 0.9│
│Americas│Mexico │0.840909│0.85│
│Americas│other │ 0.89│ 0.9│
│Americas│Peru │0.666667│0.68│
│Americas│United States│0.837709│0.85│
└────────┴─────────────┴────────┴────┘


(query;data) ddins ch
_1

dderr ''
42S02 208 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 't4bsalesrblinsidesalesccfcountrytarget'. - more error info available (1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the editing help, @Eelvex !

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I received an answer to this question through the J forum.  The J ODBC library did not support SQL Server Native Client.  That has now been fixed.